# Complex order by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

if I have a table like this

```
+----+----------------+
| id | id_alternativo |
+----+----------------+
| 15 |        18      |      
+----+----------------+
| 16 |        0       |      
+----+----------------+
| 17 |        0       |      
+----+----------------+
| 18 |        0       |
+----+----------------+
```

How can I order records to show id 18 after id 15?

Comment: do you want static sorting?

Comment: what do you mean with static sorting?

Comment: how you want sort your records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I used a simple example but my table is more complex. The id_alternativo can be recursive (id 18 could have an id_alternativo = 19) and so on and id_alternativo could not be the most high id on table so `ORDER BY id_alternativo DESC, id DESC` doesn't work. Here's a query from my table:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.compatibile, a.id_alternativo
FROM
    ordini_righe AS a
WHERE
    intestazione IN (398010) AND a.canc = 0
        AND a.stato_ordine = 0
```

Here's the result

```
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|  id   | compatibile | id_alternativo |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828924 |      0      |     828931     |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828925 |    828932   |        0       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828926 |      0      |        0       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828927 |      0      |        0       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828931 |      0      |     828933     |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828932 |    828932   |        0       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
|828933 |      0      |        0       |
+-------+-------------+----------------+
```

I had to order compatibile desc and then order the other records by the relation beetween id_alternativo and id. So i solved using a new column like this

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.compatibile, a.id_alternativo, IF(id_alternativo = 0, a.id, id_alternativo) ordine
FROM
    ordini_righe AS a
        JOIN
    locazioni AS b ON a.locazione = b.id
        JOIN
    stati_righe AS c ON a.stato_ordine = c.id
WHERE
    intestazione IN (398010) AND a.canc = 0
        AND a.stato_ordine = 0
ORDER BY compatibile DESC, ordine, a.id ASC
```

And I got the desired result

```
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|  id   | compatibile | id_alternativo | ordine |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828925 |    828932   |     828931     | 828925 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828932 |    828932   |        0       | 828932 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828926 |      0      |        0       | 828926 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828927 |      0      |        0       | 828927 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828924 |      0      |     828931     | 828931 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828931 |      0      |     828933     | 828933 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|828933 |      0      |        0       | 828933 |
+-------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the MySQL documentation you can use multiple columns in your sort and use DESC/ASC per column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

If I understand correctly what you mean your query will look as followed:

```
SELECT id, id_alternativo FROM table ORDER BY id_alternativo DESC, id DESC;

+------+----------------+
| id   | id_alternativo |
+------+----------------+
|   15 |             18 |
|   18 |              0 |
|   17 |              0 |
|   16 |              0 |
+------+----------------+
```

Comment: I think the OP wants all alternative ids following the main id (15, then 18 because is an alternative id of 15, then 16, 17, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a self join like this:

```
select t.*
from
  yourtable t left join yourtable o
  on t.id = o.id_alternativo
order by
  coalesce(o.id, t.id), t.id
```

this will put all alternative ids after the main id (in this case 18 will follow 15).

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8625d/2). Please note that this will work unless an alternative id has another alternative id (e.g. if 18 itself has another alternative id) but this cannot be solved purely with MySQL as it does not support recursive queries yet.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works if an alternative id hasn't an alternative id itself, but in my case it could. Btw I've found a solution and I've posted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand just use `order by id (18, 15)` and any other id you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,id_alternativo  
from table_name
order by case id  when 15 Then 1
                  when 18 Then 2
                  when 16 Then 3
                  when 17 Then 4
          else 5
          end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use order like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytab
ORDER BY IF(id=18,155,id*10);
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> select id from mytab;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
+----+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT id
    -> FROM mytab
    -> ORDER BY IF(id=18,155,id*10);
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 18 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 19 |
+----+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```